# Reading from Perl pipe child process hanging on last element of handle array

Tags: perl, pipe, fork

When running the following code, the last server is not printed - the script 'hangs' after the second-last array element.

```
my %readers;
my $command = "pgrep -f weblogic.Name";

foreach my $server(@servers) {
    pipe($readers{$server},WRITER);
    unless(my $pid = fork()) {
        my $response = qx(ssh -q oracle\@$server "$command");
        print WRITER $response;
        exit();
    }   
}


foreach my $server (@servers) {
     my $fh = $readers{$server};
     my @procs = <$fh>;
     chomp(@procs);
     for my $proc (@procs) {
          printf "%s\t%s\n", substr($server,8), $proc;
     }   
 }

 print "end\n";
```

The output is as follows:

```
$ ./get_stuck.pl  
92      18196
93      27420
94      17635
95      10258
96      10831
```

There should be a server '97' output after '96', yet there is not, and the script just hangs/stops at that point.

If I change the reader section to use a string instead of an array as follows:

```
foreach my $server (@servers) {
    my $fh = $readers{$server};
    my $procs = <$fh>;
    printf "%s\n", $server;
}
```

...then the script prints all servers including '97', however, if there are multiple results from the command, this will only print the first result (seems to break on newline). In other words, if the command returns 3 process ids for a given server, only the first process id is printed.

Any suggestions on why using an array causes the script to hang on the last element? Or perhaps (less desirable) how I might use a string, but retrieve all results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually tried it, but:

This code looks like you're deadlocking yourself.

- `<` `>` in list context slurps the whole file, i.e. it reads until it reaches end-of-file (EOF).
- The file handle in question refers to a pipe.
- The read end of a pipe reaches EOF when all open handles to the write end are closed.
- You never close `WRITER` in the parent (the child implicitly closes it on exit).
- Thus the parent is stuck reading from the pipe while holding the write end open.

The reason this only happens for the last array element is because you're using a bareword filehandle (`WRITER`), which is effectively a global variable. Re-opening the same handle implicitly closes it first; i.e. the (n+1)th iteration of the loop closes the nth pipe. Only the last `WRITER` is left open.

If I'm right, then the fix is:

```
foreach my $server(@servers) {
    pipe($readers{$server},WRITER);
    unless(my $pid = fork()) {
        my $response = qx(ssh -q oracle\@$server "$command");
        print WRITER $response;
        exit();
    }
    close WRITER;  # always close WRITER in the parent
}
```

But I would also recommend changing the code to this:

```
foreach my $server (@servers) {
    pipe($readers{$server}, my $WRITER);
    defined(my $pid = fork()) or die "$0: fork: $!\n";
    unless($pid) {
        my $response = qx(ssh -q oracle\@$server "$command");
        print $WRITER $response;
        exit();
    }
    close $WRITER;
}
```

I.e. check `fork` for errors and use a lexical variable instead of a bareword filehandle. In this case the `close` is actually optional because `$WRITER` is implicitly closed at the end of its scope (the current loop iteration) because there are no other references to it.

You could simplify it a bit more by using pipe open:

```
foreach my $server (@servers) {
    open $readers{$server}, '-|', 'ssh', '-q', "oracle\@$server", $command
        or die "$0: ssh: $!\n";
}
```

Finally,

```
my $fh = $readers{$server};
my @procs = <$fh>;
```

could be reduced to

```
my @proces = readline $readers{$server};
```

(I don't like the `<` `>` operator. In my opinion always writing either `readline` or `glob` explicitly makes it more readable.)

Comment: I thought of unclosed `WRITER` as well.  I still don't see how the scalar read on `<$fh>` changes it ... am I missing that somewhere?

Comment: @zdim In scalar context you only get the first line (or in OP's words, "*however, if there are multiple results from the command, this will only print the first result (seems to break on newline)*"), whereas list context will read all lines, which necessitates blocking until EOF is reached.

Comment: Excellent! I did try closing WRITER, but I did it within the `unless` statement, not after it. I have updated my code to use a lexical variable as you suggested, but still included the explicit `close` statement for clarity. Thanks very much for your help. Champion.